# CUDA program returning incorrect results

Tags: cuda

I have copied a vector addition example from the book "CUDA By Example" and I am getting unexpected incorrect results.  Here is my code

```
#define N (33*1024)

__global__
void add(int *a, int *b,int *c){
    int tid = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    while (tid < N){
        c[tid] = a[tid]+b[tid];
        tid+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }
}


int main()
{

    int a[N], b[N], c[N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a,N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b,N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,N*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0 ; i<N;i++){
        a[i]= -i;
        b[i]= i*i;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a,a,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b,b,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c,c,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    add<<<128,128>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);

    cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    bool success=true;

    //print results
    for(int i=0; i<N;i++){

        if((a[i]+b[i])!=c[i]){
            printf("Error: %d + %d != %d\n",a[i],b[i],c[i]);
            success=false;
        }

    }

    if(success) printf("we did it!\n");
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_a);

    printf("done");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and I am getting a bunch of incorrect addition results, here is just a few

```
Error: -33784 + 1141358656 != 255
Error: -33785 + 1141426225 != 0
Error: -33786 + 1141493796 != 0
Error: -33787 + 1141561369 != 0
Error: -33788 + 1141628944 != 4609792
Error: -33789 + 1141696521 != 0
Error: -33790 + 1141764100 != 4207408
```

and there are many many more.  I am a complete CUDA beginner but my guess is I either

A) copied the code incorrectly from the book OR

B) the incorrect results come from the fact that I am using CUDA 10 which came out long after this book was written

EDIT:  I restarted my computer and it worked

Answer (score -3):

I happen to be able to repeat your error if I alter my configuration. Something is probably wrong with your configuration, too. When I used fitting CUDA and driver versions it worked after fixing a minor typo:

```
cudaFree(dev_a); //this line is copied three times in your code
```

Please wrap your cuda call with something like the following to check the return value. Must be one of the cuda functions failed.

```
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) {                                                    \
        cudaError_t _m_cudaStat = value;                                              \
        if (_m_cudaStat != cudaSuccess) {                                             \
                fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",                   \
                                cudaGetErrorString(_m_cudaStat), __LINE__, __FILE__); \
                exit(1);                                                              \
        } }
//for example
     CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

It should tell you what might go wrong.

Comment: "I happen to be able to repeat your error" -- so if you can repeat the problem, why not tell us what it is and how to fix it rather than posting a useless answer suggesting checking for errors

Comment: I have cuda7.5 and cuda8.0, nivida driver 352.68, obviously the driver version does not work with cuda8.0, and if cuda8.0 is used, the cuda* functions fails, and kernel never get executed. Everyone get different configuration, check the return value and post here will know.  Have you try run it before comment?

Comment: You haven't answered my question -- you write that can reproduce the problem. Why don't you tell us what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: I think I didn't say it very clear somehow, I 1st try your code with cuda7.5, everything works as expected, except the typo I point out. Then I try cuda 8.0, one of the cudaMemcpy() function return error code, the error string says my GPU driver and cuda 8.0 does not compatible, and the result is garbage, because none of the cuda* function run properly, and the kernel is not properly executed on GPU, you need check the return value to know if yours is exactly the same.

Comment: OK, what I mean is the program is mostly fine. your cuda environment may have issue. If you check return value, it should give clue what might be wrong.

Comment: I see your answer regarding What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API? while, this one is about forget to check run-time API error, not how to check runtime error.